# When use TransactionScope get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: sql-server, transactionscope

We are using TransactionScope for the transaction,

`IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
Timeout = 20 min 
TransactionScopeOption = TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`

can not understand this exception

**Exception Message of System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid
>   for the state of the transaction. ---> System.TimeoutException:
>   Transaction Timeout     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction
>   tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction, Guid
>   promoterType)     at
>   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Guid promoterType)     --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---     at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition&
>   command, Action`2 paramReader)     at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition&
>   command)     at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String
>   sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType).

also, get below error

***System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.***

**Exception Message of Execution Timeout Expired:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout
>   Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)     at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd,
>   Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior)     at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.d__138`1.MoveNext()     at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)     at
>   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param,
>   IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)

Comment: Please provide the full exception message and stacktrace (like from `Exception.ToString()`).

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have added exception trace in question